# <p:chart> does not display the charts

Tags: primefaces, charts, dialog

I have a dialog component of primefaces that contains a p:chart. First time when the page loads it does not display the dialog. When I refresh the page and click on the command link that shows the dialog it works.

Comment: Can you add some code for what you have so far? We can't help you with a solution without it

Comment: Does it not display the dialog as you state in your text or not the charts in it? Never the less, make title and text consistent and show an [mcve] and also post version info like stated in http://www.stackofverflow.com/tags/jsf/info